# Defining Oblique Lines

Tags: geometry

Is it correct to classify a line which is neither vertical nor horizontal as oblique.  I am trying to classify lines in a plane based on the quadrants through which they pass.

Comment: Sure. But there is nothing absolute about the notion, since horizontal and vertical depend on choice of axes.